# How to edit an existing excel file with JXL

Tags: java, jxl

When I open a file using `WritableWorkbook` and add some data to it the data that was already in the file gets erased. Is there any way to edit data in specific cells while preserving the preexisting data?

Comment: The source has many examples in the package `jxl.demo`. The `ReadWrite` class seems to show an example of opening an Excel file, modifying it, and then saving it.

Comment: Is it possible to make a copy of it in another file or variable before changing it ?